# Failed to Store ArrayList<String> in SharedPreferences in Android using JAVA ?

Tags: java, android, arraylist, sharedpreferences

here is the code to save ArrayList in SharedPreferences in Android  but getting error at this LOC :

```
 myAList.add(sEdit.getString("val"+j,""));
```

BY Indicating that

> The method getString(String) is undefined for the type SharedPreferences.EditorThe method getString(String) is undefined for the type SharedPreferences.Editor

```
public static void setValuesInSession(Context c,ArrayList<String> myArrayList)
{
    SharedPreferences sPrefs=PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(c);
    SharedPreferences.Editor sEdit=sPrefs.edit();

    for(int i=0;i<myArrayList.size();i++)
    {
             sEdit.putString("val"+i,myArrayList.get(i));
    }
     sEdit.putInt("size",myArrayList.size());
     sEdit.commit();

}
public static ArrayList<String> getValuesOfSession(Context c)
{
    SharedPreferences sPrefs=PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(c);
    SharedPreferences.Editor sEdit=sPrefs.edit();
    ArrayList<String> myAList=new ArrayList<String>();
    int size=sPrefs.getInt("size",0);

    for(int j=0;j<size;j++)
    {
     // Log.i("MYlIST ADD",""+);
         myAList.add(sEdit.getString("val"+j,""));
    }
    return myAList;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your are trying to obtain string value from Editor instead of retrieving it from SharedPreferences.

replace

```
myAList.add(sEdit.getString("val"+j,""));
```

with

```
myAList.add(sPrefs.getString("val"+j,""));
```

Resulting

```
public static ArrayList<String> getValuesOfSession(Context c)
{
    SharedPreferences sPrefs=PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(c);
    ArrayList<String> myAList=new ArrayList<String>();
    int size=sPrefs.getInt("size",0);

    for(int j=0;j<size;j++)
    {
     // Log.i("MYlIST ADD",""+);
         myAList.add(sPrefs.getString("val"+j,""));
    }
    return myAList;
}
```

And it is not advised to call local variables starting with "s" since the Android Code Style guidelines encourage to call non-final static fields starting with s and non-public member fields starting with m.

Comment: yes your answer is right can u pls help me will it save whole list whatever the list i provided to the function

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
for(int i=0;i<myArrayList.size();i++)
    {
             sEdit.putString("val"+i,myArrayList.get(i).toString());
    }
```

Below is my code.. I did same as you.. working...

```
SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext());
             SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
             editor.putInt("Size", languageNames.size());

             for(int i=0; i<languageNames.size(); i++)
             {
                 editor.putString("data" + i, languageNames.get(i).toString());
             }

             editor.putString("ID",id);
             editor.putString("Email", email);
             editor.putString("Birthday", birthday);
             editor.putString("Username", username);
             editor.putString("Location", location);
             editor.putString("Gender", gender);
             editor.commit();
```

Get data...

```
ArrayList<String> languageNames = new ArrayList<String>();

    SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext());

            int array_size = preferences.getInt("Size", 0);
            id = preferences.getString("ID", "");
            username = preferences.getString("Username", "");
            email = preferences.getString("Email", "");
            birthday = preferences.getString("Birthday", "");
            location = preferences.getString("Location", "");
            gender = preferences.getString("Gender", "");  

            languageNames.clear();
            for(int i=0; i<array_size; i++)
            {
                languageNames.add(preferences.getString("data" + i, "").toString());
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
       public static ArrayList<String> getValuesOfSession(Context c) {
       SharedPreferences sPrefs=PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(c);
       ArrayList<String> myAList=new ArrayList<String>();
       int size=sPrefs.getInt("size",0);

       for(int j=0;j<size;j++)
       {
        // Log.i("MYlIST ADD",""+);
            myAList.add(sPrefs.getString("val"+j,""));
       }
       return myAList;
   }
```